# How to read from numbered txt files? (data1.txt, data2.txt, etc)

Tags: c++

This is what I'm doing right now in order to read from multiple txt files. What would be a better way to deal with this? I would like to store the results in separate vectors (what I'm calling `out1`, `out2`, etc. here).
The data contains XY coordinates which I'm doing a Hough transform of.

```
ifstream data1, data2, data3, data4;
vector< vector<float> > XY1, XY2, XY3, XY4;
vector<float> row1(2), row2(2), row3(2), row4(2);
vector<CircleData> out1, out2, out3, out4;


// Read data
data1.open("data1.txt");
while (data1 >> row1[0] >> row1[1])
{
    XY1.push_back(row1);
}
data1.close();
// Convert XY-coordinates to pixels with image size as parameter
CoordinatesToImage convert1(XY1, 300);
// Do Hough transformation, then search for the strongest circles in the data 
CircleHough test1;
out1 = test1.houghPeaks(test1.houghTransform(convert1.getScan(), radius), radius, 7);


// Next data file, same procedure
data2.open("data2.txt");
while (data2 >> row2[0] >> row2[1])
{
    XY2.push_back(row2);
}
data2.close();
// Convert XY-coordinates to pixels with image size as parameter
CoordinatesToImage convert2(XY2, 300);
// Do Hough transformation, then search for the strongest circles in the data 
CircleHough test2;
out2 = test2.houghPeaks(test2.houghTransform(convert2.getScan(), radius), radius, 7);


// Next data file, same procedure
data3.open("data3.txt");
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this seems like a typical code generalization problem (so i won't go into details regarding this specific example). There's propably a lot of different ways of dealing with this, but this would be a way by refactoring the existing code base.

As pointed out in your code comments, the repeating code is the part responsible for reading and processing the file input so i would recommend starting by trying to write that part into it´s own subroutine by using variables when necessary. For instance (returning the resulting vector):

```
vector<CircleData> read_and_process_file_input(std::string filename)
{
    // Read data
    ifstream data (filename);
    vector<float> row(2);
    vector<vector<float>> XY;

    while (data >> row[0] >> row[1])
    {
        XY.push_back(row);
    }
    data.close();
    // Convert XY-coordinates to pixels with image size as parameter
    CoordinatesToImage convert1(XY, 300);
    // Do Hough transformation, then search for the strongest circles in the data 
    CircleHough test1;
    return test1.houghPeaks(test1.houghTransform(convert1.getScan(), radius), radius, 7);
}
```

You can iterate over this with a for loop (indexing starting from 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i < no_files+1; i++)
    read_and_process_file_input("data" + i + ".txt");
```

If you don't know the number of input files or if you want to avoid hard-coding those you would have to add existence check 
for each new input file.

How you want to store the resulting data depends largely on the application; You could use a data structure to replace variables out*.
Alternatively (knowing the no of input files) it might be more efficient to store those in a matrix (each output data as a column)

Comment: Beautiful. However, I get an error at `read_and_process_file_input("data" + i + ".txt");`. "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type". I tried with a string instead and converting `"data" + i + ".txt"` to string, but that didn't work.

Comment: Yea, there's a syntax error (+ notation doesn't work with C primitive char*). Trying the std::string instead, did you change the argument definition (char *filename)->(std::string filename)?

Comment: Yeah, I did. However, I didn't set my path right which was the problem. Thank you very much! It works now

Answer (score 1):

Add a method.

```
void do_something(std::string file_name){
    ifstream data1{file_name};
    vector< vector<float> > XY;
    while (data1 >> row1[0] >> row1[1])
    {
        XY.push_back(row1);
    }
    data1.close();
    // Convert XY-coordinates to pixels with image size as parameter
    CoordinatesToImage convert1(XY, 300);
    // Do Hough transformation, then search for the strongest circles in the data 
    CircleHough test1;
    out1 = test1.houghPeaks(test1.houghTransform(convert1.getScan(), radius), radius, 7);
}
```

Comment: This I can get behind. Upvoted, but recommend a quick example of usage with a couple calls to the function or a loop.